# antlr: missing package declaration in generated Lexer source

Tags: java, antlr

I am using one .g file for both lexer and parser. I have the following lines in the grammar file:

```
@header {
package foo.bar;
}
```

However I found that package line is only put into the generated parser source file, and missing in the FooLexer.java file. Anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: It's in the [documentation](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Grammars).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@header {
package foo.bar;
}
```

is short for:

```
@parser::header {
package foo.bar;
}
```

To put a package declaration in the lexer, do:

```
@lexer::header {
package foo.bar;
}
```

The same goes for `@members { ... }`, which is short for `@parser::members { ... }`. There's also `@lexer::members { ... }` to put variables/methods etc. in the lexer.